# BreezeJs - Array of complex types with inheritance metadata

Tags: c#, angularjs, mongodb, breeze

I am using BreezeJs with AngularJs to communicate with a web API with MongoDB backend and am having trouble defining the metadata for one of the documents where I need an array of complex types with inheritance.

This is the MongoDB document

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53f2f0f117166f1e6898cc32"),
  "Name" : "SectionContainer1",
  "Sections" : [{
     "_t" : "SectionA",
     "Title" : "sdf sdaf dsfsdfdsfsdfds"
  }, {
     "_t" : "SectionB",
     "Title" : "sdf sdaf dsfsdfdsfsdfds"
  }, {
     "_t" : "SectionC",
     "_id" : "53f38e1317166f196025849b",
     "Title" : "sdf sdaf dsfsdfdsfsdfds"
  }]
}
```

and the class structure

```
public class SectionContainer
{
   public ObjectId Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public List<BaseSection> Sections{get;set;}
}

public class BaseSection
{
   public string Title{get;set;}
}

public class SectionA : BaseSection
{
   ...
}

public class SectionB : BaseSection
{
   ...
}

public class SectionC : BaseSection
{
   ...
}
```

This is what I am trying to do in BreezeJs

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('metadataFactory', ['breeze', metadataFactory]);

function metadataFactory(breeze) {
    var addType, DATE, DT, helper, ID;

    // The metadata definition service
    return {
        fillMetadataStore: fillMetadataStore
    };

    /*** Implementation ***/
    function fillMetadataStore(metadataStore, serviceName) {
        init(metadataStore, serviceName);

        addTypes();
    }

    function addTypes() {
        addType({
            name: 'SectionContainer',
            dataProperties: {
                id: { isPartOfKey: true },
                name: { nullOk: true },
                sections: { complexTypeName: "BaseSection", hasMany: true }
            }
        });

        addType({
            name: 'BaseSection',
            isAbstract: true,
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                id: { isPartOfKey: true },
                title: { nullOk: true }
            }
        });

        addType({
            name: 'SectionA',
            isComplexType: true,
            baseTypeName: "BaseSection",
            dataProperties: {
                id: { isPartOfKey: true },
                title: { nullOk: true },
            }
        });

        addType({
            name: 'SectionB',
            isComplexType: true,
            baseTypeName: "BaseSection",
            dataProperties: {
                id: { isPartOfKey: true },
                title: { nullOk: true },
            }
        });

        addType({
            name: 'SectionC',
            isComplexType: true,
            baseTypeName: "BaseSection",
            dataProperties: {
                id: { isPartOfKey: true },
                title: { nullOk: true },
            }
        });
    }

    // Initialize the metdataFactory with convenience fns and variables 
    function init(metadataStore, serviceName) {

        var store = metadataStore; // the metadataStore that we'll be filling

        // 'Identity' is the default key generation strategy for this app
        var keyGen = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;

        // Breeze Labs: breeze.metadata.helper.js
        // https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.metadata-helper.js
        // The helper reduces data entry by applying common conventions
        // and converting common abbreviations (e.g., 'type' -> 'dataType')
        helper = new breeze.config.MetadataHelper(namespace, keyGen);
        helper.addDataService(store, serviceName);

        // addType - make it easy to add the type to the store using the helper
        addType = function (type) { return helper.addTypeToStore(store, type); };

        // DataTypes we'll be using
        DT = breeze.DataType;
        DATE = DT.DateTime;
        ID = DT.Int32;
    }
  }
})();
```

Unfortunately Breeze does not seem to allow for inheritance in complex types and due to the way the data is formatted in MongoDB the sections are not their own entity. Is it possible to represent data like this in Breeze and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the Breeze.js docs -

> Complex types do not have identities (key properties in breeze) and therefore cannot exist independently. Complex types can only exist as properties on entity types or other complex types.

So to answer your question, no they cannot exist without a parent.  Also you cannot set a key on a complex type as it is invalid.  That is the nature of complex types not only in Breeze but in similar systems that I am familiar with.

I started to write up an answer for you that was an alternative but after reviewing your question I found a few problems that will not work and I wasn't sure if there was something that you knew that I didn't so I figured I would point the obvious out to see if it helped at all -

```
addType({
    name: 'BaseSection',
    // I don't believe this is a valid property
    isAbstract: true,
    isComplexType: true,
    dataProperties: {
        // Complex types cannot have keys
        id: { isPartOfKey: true },
        title: { nullOk: true }
    }
});
```

I am sure you already knew that so it seemed that the code you are using is pseudo-code.  If that is the case then I would only have two recommendations -

1. Define the entity on the server in your model definition to have already inherited what is needed and have the unused properties still available on the client but would be null until returned.
2. Use Breeze entities instead of trying to use complex types.  It doesn't seem that the model you are trying to use is the right direction as of course mentioned when stating that you can't have a key property on them but that is the only property besides the title.  You can always have a reference back to the parent object and re-use the Id's as long as they are in a different collection, so this is valid -

   addType({
       name: 'BaseSection',
       dataProperties: {
           id: { type: ID },
           title: { nullOk: true }
       }
   });

   addType({
       name: 'SectionA',
       dataProperties: {
           id: { type: ID },
           title: { nullOk: true }
       },
       navigationProperties: {
           baseSection: 'BaseSection'
       }
   });

The problem here is you need to let Breeze know the property id on SectionA should match the BaseSection which is easy to do but given this shorthand metadata format you are using I am not familiar with how to do that.  In long hand that property would look something like this -

```
"navigationProperties": [
    {
        "name": "baseSection",
        "entityTypeName": "BaseSection",
        "isScalar": true,
        "associationName": "SectionA_BaseSection"
    },
]
```